# Should I refrigerate vegetables in sealed bag or not?

Tags: storage-method, vegetables, refrigerator

Supermarkets sell vegetables in sealed bags. Best to refrigerate bags with vegetables inside, or take vegetables out of bags before putting them in refrigerator?
 [Here are more pics](https://foodsecurityfoodjustice.com/2017/05/06/find-hidden-hunger-walking-tour-in-hk/) of vegetables sold in sealed bags.

I can't make up my mind. If I take them out of bag, then cold refrigerator air will dry them. If I keep them in bag, they can't intake carbon dioxide, and the oxygen they keep exhaling will kill them!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hints on storage of vegetables and fruit](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16134/hints-on-storage-of-vegetables-and-fruit)

Comment: @moscafj No? It doesn't talk about SEALED produce?

Comment: Middle ground : poke some  holes in the bags ?

Comment: Test: buy 2 bags and store one in original package, one out and see how they fare in a week or so. Write an answer when you have the results.

Comment: Those bags could be permeable to gases, and it may not be possible to tell from looking at them.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Some fridges have a special area to store vegetables where they control the air flow and temperature in order to control moisture and humidity.

If your fridge is one of these, then removing them from the sealed bags is not a bad idea.

However, if you don't have such an area the vegetables are likely to dry or to get cold burns depending on your fridge settings, so keeping them packaged can help avoid that.

It is also important to notice that keeping things tidy and in separate containers in a fridge helps with higiene and keeps harmful bacteria from damaged products to latch onto newer ones.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Another point (for when there isn’t a special drawer in your fridge):  vegetables kept in plastic bags can get very wet with condensation so I poke a big hole in the end as I store them. I’m not certain that improves the keeping time, but that’s why I do it.

Answer (score 0):

The way they are packaged is important.  Some salad greens are packed in a nitrogen atmosphere, which means the air inside the bag has had all the oxygen removed and replaced with nitrogen instead (normal air is 78% nitrogen so increasing this up to 100% is of no health concern).  But it means oxygen-breathing bacteria on the leaves will find it difficult to grow inside the sealed bag (at least until the oxygen gets back in, one way or another), prolonging the life of the fresh greens.

If you empty them out of the bag then you are providing the bacteria with a literal breath of fresh air, helping to kick start them on their journey of turning your fresh greens into compost.

I'm also not sure that cut leaves do much in the way of oxygen production.  For a start, once removed from the plant they no longer receive fresh water and nutrients from the sap.  Oxygen is also only produced during photosynthesis, which requires light.  So if the light is off in your fridge when the door is shut, they won't be able to produce any oxygen anyway.  (In fact most plants stop taking in carbon dioxide in the dark and [consume a small amount of oxygen instead](https://www.indianapublicmedia.org/amomentofscience/sleeping-with-plants.php).)